# Is this .htaccess rule malicious?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I found some changes to my .htaccess file, my site has been compromised in the past couple of months, but only with new php files or modifying some of the existing ones from my web application. I have been cleaning those up manually myself, but since I'm not the only one modifying the code in the site, some of the changes are not evident to me if were added by someone else in the team or if it's the cause of the site being compromised.

I found these new lines in the .htaccess, and I have no idea if they're used for something "good" or if it's yet another attempt of breaking into my site.

According to my git history, the `FilesMatch` directive was removed, but the two rewrite rules at the bottom were added:

```
<FilesMatch ".*">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+-rid-[0-9]+\.html)$ \.404\.php?f=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{8})$ \.404\.php?f=$1 [L]
```

My files are currently a mess, but I can't get ahold of the rest of the team - they work overseas - and I don't want to leave my site even more compromised than the way it already is.

The 404.php file referenced in those rules only has this line of code:

```
header( 'Location: /' );
```

I didn't add that file, but also I don't see how that could be an issue - I may be wrong of course.

Anyone experienced in .htaccess rules and some security who can tell me if I'm safe to leave those rules in place?

Comment: remove both rules and `.404.php` if they are not added by your team

Comment: I can't know if the team added those until after several hours when they get back online